# cocoa-touch PSPDFKIT How can I get value from PDF files?

Tags: cocoa-touch, pspdfkit

Just a quick questions is How can I get delegate, results or call back from buttons, check boxes, text fields... that are located on the PDF file.

To be clearer, I'm working on a project that are PDF test forms with a bundle of multi-chooses questions, some text fields and a button to submit them. I need to get these details that user entered.

It seems to be this delegate, but it doesn't work

```
- (void)pdfViewController:(PSPDFViewController *)pdfController didShowAnnotationView:(UIView<PSPDFAnnotationView> *)annotationView onPageView:(PSPDFPageView *)pageView;
```

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of the [PSPDFKit PDF SDK](http://pspdfkit.com/). While this framework does support features like text selection and annotation highlighting/drawing, there's no support yet for PDF forms yet. This might change later in 2013.

Update: PSPDFKit v3 now fully supports PDF Forms - you can play around with the demo, no registration required.

Comment: You are doing a great job dude.